# repeating model possible?

Tags: mesh

So lets say I have a simple cube and I want to make 10 of these cubes, all lined up right next to each other, with the same distance between each. If I change one of these cubes, I don't want to make the same change on 9 more cubes. Is there a way to basically repeat this cube 9 times, so that I only need to make a change on one cube to affect them all? It's basically like the mirror tool, but used to repeat the model instead. Is there something like this in Blender?

Comment: You can use also dupliframes, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/how-to-efficiently-instantiate-object-with-memory-hungry-modifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an unapplied  Array Modifier.

[image: array modifier]