# Getting hair vertices via python

Tags: scripting, python, particles

We can [convert hair into 3D editable objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/) [via the modifier tab](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181/290), this means there must be an API to get the hair vertices instantly from python.

Can you explain it and all it's parameters and arguments?

I need it to start my project "Pholygonal", a polygonal hair generator controlled by the hair particle system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a little snippet that prints out all the coordinates of the hair vertices from the first particle system on a selected object. Make sure the object has a *hair* particle system.

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.object
hairs = object.particle_systems[0].particles
for i, h in enumerate(hairs):
    print('hair number {i}:'.format(i=i))
    for i, hv in enumerate(h.hair_keys):
        print('  vertex {i} coordinates: {co}'.format(i=i, co=hv.co))
```

`particle_systems[0]` is used to get to the first particle system of the object. After this the `particles` are all the particles in the system (in this case the hairs). The hair vertices are accessed with `hair_keys`. Finally to get the coordinates of a hair vertex you use `co`.

If you want the coordinate of only one hair vertex, you could type it in one nasty line:

`bpy.context.object.particle_systems[0].particles[0].hair_keys[0].co`