# How to export hair particles to stl file?

Tags: export

I have created hair for a human model in Blender, but exporting my creation into STL format does not work properly. When I re-import the exported STL file, there is no longer hair on the human model.

How can I combine the human model and the hair into one mesh?

Comment: Have you converted the particles to meshes like here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects ? If so you could join the meshes before export.