# How do I get hair particles to show up when exported?

Tags: export, particles, hair

I made some hair particles, but when I export it to .dae only the object under it shows up. Did I skip something? How do I get it to show?[image: In Blender]

[image: In export]

Comment: You don't say to what format you export, but these are related (the first one possibly a duplicate): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/how-to-export-hair-particles-to-stl-file and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects

Comment: Oops, it's .dae. I tried the solutions in the questions you linked to, but when I convert it, it just turns to solid color and loses the hair-like appearance.

Comment: If your hairs are just simple strands (i.e. not duplicated objects), you'll get a mesh consisting of only vertices and edges, no faces. I never export to external formats, and only rarely import, so I've never really had to deal with this specific problem, and therefore I'm not sure what the best solution would be.