# How do I import my Hair emission particles with my object into another blender project?

Tags: materials, objects, export, particles, import

I just made a feather and i'm trying to to put this into another project i get the quill but not the hair emissions. what am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Importing to Other 3d Packages**
If you're importing the object with hair into another program (3d package / game engine etc.) most likely you will want to convert the hair particles into real objects, see [How can I convert a hair-particle system into 3D, editable objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects) Note that particles won't be available for tweaking like particles because they won't be particles, rather than meshes.

**Importing to Blender New Projects**
If you want only to import object with particles into another Blender project then just import it as object with standard [Link / Append](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html) operators (enter *Objects* folder while browsing main .blend file); modifiers will be imported as well along with the particle system.

Comment: He did not ask how to import it into another application but into another blender project.

Comment: @Brain the procedure importing into another Blender project is described in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy ;)

The particle system is bound to an blender object and you can import it by appending it from another blender file by choosing the object to which you have attached it.

For example if you set a particle system to a cube, save the file, open a new file and choose file-append, select your file with the particle system and that's it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the hair to real objects.  To do this, click the convert button as shown below.
[image: convert]