# How can I apply hair dynamics?

Tags: particles, hair

How can I apply hair dynamics?

I don't want to [convert it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects), I want to continue to edit it in particle edit mode

Answer (score 1):

I don't know free solution, but with paid Hair Tool you can convert simulated hair to  curves, and then attach those curves back as particle hairs - but this time with ability to edit them (comb, cut etc).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you already figured this out, but when the hair is going all over the place, if you want the hair to move together like a head of hair or like a main, you need to set the voxel size high enough, 1.0 is a good start, and then set the hair target hair density to 0.5, and target strength to something like 0.01.  Goal strength i set to 0.3 for cloth and for hair.  That should get you going in the right direction.

Under field weights wind can be an issue, OH and your hair may to heavy at 0.3kg, try 0.08 kg to start, maybe less.

this the same answer I posted for another user for default settings, in addtion, you have to click hair dynamics.  You need to set the settings above, and then you'll likely need to lower some of the field settings, all of them are set to 1.0 by default.