# Appending an object brings duplicated objects

Tags: objects, append

I have a scene with three sets of three bricks, nine in total. I created eight of them by duplicating the first one and modifying them. In another scene I append one of the bricks. I get the brick I want plus the brick(s) that were used to create it.

How can I correct this?

In the bricks file I have tried *Make duplicates real* and also *Make single user*.

Comment: possibly related. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend

Comment: Can you delete the original brick, or is it part of the same object as the other ones?

Comment: iKlsR  Thanks but not really. My wall will have doglegs and I will need to edit the mesh bricks.

Comment: CharlesL. Yes that is the way. When I delete the first three bricks (the simplest ones) the other six can be appended without dragging any others into the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the answers in the comments, it looks like you can solve the problem by simply deleting the erroneously copied brick(s).

To avoid this problem entirely in the future, you can used an *Array* modifier on the bricks, then separate them into individually manipulatable meshes using the techniques outlined at [How can I use an array modifier to create individually manipulatable objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109/array-modifier-to-create-individually-manipulatable-objects).

A third option, depending on the kind of manipulation you are doing to the brick meshes, would be to automate the randomness of the bricks using a *Displace* modifier (applied after applying an *Array* modifier). In order to make each one of the bricks have a different deformation, set the *Displace* modifier setting 'Texture Coordinates' to object and select any object in your scene (though preferably an empty).

Comment: Thanks @Gwenn. 
 Replying in order of your answers. It was actually better to delete the bricks that were used for copying as this broke the link to the bricks that were copied. Also it is easier to create three bricks without chamfers than six bricks with only some edges chamfered.
Array modifier: Thanks for that, it will be useful.
Displace modifier: This will be useful in the future for ordinary walls. 
This is a training exercise for me and I really appreciate the help in not just what to do but how to do it and with alternatives.
Much appreciated.
Stephen