# Array modifier (vary textures on duplicates)

Tags: texturing, modifiers

Using the array modifier and textures, can the individual array objects be slightly textured differently for individual look?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/can-i-use-an-image-sequence-with-offset-frames-as-a-texture-on-array-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31517/how-to-offset-the-texture-coordinates-of-an-object-with-an-array-modifier-for-ma).  You might find the best answer informative.  I needed to solve the same problem and this solved it for me.  Good luck.

Comment: This is awesome!  Thanks for the feedback.  I know it has been a while since I submitted this question i, but I really need this.  Both answers on that related question help me.

Answer (score 8):

Well seeing as you said 'slightly' then yes, you can have *slightly* different textures on an object that has been arrayed:

[image]

This cube has a texture which uses 'Generated' coordinates instead of other texture mapping coordinates such as UV.

Generated coordinates can be set for either the internal renderer in the mapping panel of the texture settings:

[image]

Or in Cycles with a 'Texture Coordinate' node:

[image]

The example above uses a procedural cloud texture with generated coordinates. This method doesn't allow you to specify *different* textures to appear on each cube, however, it does allow you to slightly vary each different cube.

Comment: Thanks, I'm modeling a box of cigars and I guess I can work with the generated values instead of a texture of tobacco leaf. I'll try that.

Comment: It's only the mapping coordinates that are generated. You can use a texture as long as it is tileable instead of a procedural one.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, not easily at least.

Some options you could use for UV coords.

- UV Project (after the array modifier).
- Vertex group modifier, then UV-warp modifier and use vertex weights as an influence.
- Vertex group modifier, then use vertex weights to modify the texture (cycles nodes can do this).

There may be other ways you could tweak values, but they dont give good control. You may be better of looking into dupli-frames (dupli objects in general).

Comment: Thanks, I'm modeling a box of cigars and I'll try the one above but I really want to use a texture.  I can convert the array to individual objects and do them individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cycles you can probably do something tricky, like a math node with greater than, getting in the generated coordinates as an input on one axis; then you could probably UV different textures based on that.
you'd need an extra math node for each "instance" btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Input->Geometry node to get a vector value that varies with each object created by the Array modifier. You can use a Converter->Vector-math node to add it to the UV coordinates from a Texture coordinate node.

Been looking for this for *ages*... finally found a way!

Comment: Actually this is a rubbish answer. Sorry. It does produce per array-object offsets, but it warps the UV map.

Comment: Why not delete it then? Press delete at the bottom of your answer.