# Array a Group of objects?

Tags: groups

Is it possible to array a group of objects?

For example, if I have three objects in a group, (I want to keep them as separate objects) is it possible to easily duplicate them as if I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for every single one?

Comment: What's wrong with using _Alt+D_? Also a possible duplicate of [Array modifier to create individually manipulatable objects?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109/array-modifier-to-create-individually-manipulatable-objects)

Comment: @Aldrik I don't want to *create* individual objects, I want to array multiple objects. (multiple objects in, multiple objects out.) and Alt+D is just too tedious for large amounts objects. :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This answer was inspired by this answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24392/3127)

here is a solution that actually allows use to use the array modifier to duplicate grouped objects. It does, however, require one extra mesh.

We begin with our grouped object:

[image]

Then add a plane. Go into the object properties for that plane, and enter the instancing tab ([called duplication in 2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLx1z.png)). Select faces.

[image]

Finally, select your group object then your plane, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to parent them, selecting *Object*.

[image]

Now, finally, if you add an array modifier to your plane, the group object will be duplicated:

[image]

Demo file to see final result:

[image]

Comment: good method but after setting the count to some number and if we want to delete or hide the plane the hole array disappears. How to delete the plane that is unwanted. I donot want to apply the array modifier and just want to delete the plane which we have insert. Is it possible..

Comment: @atek during my tests the planes did not show up in renders - but yes, there is no way to hid them.

Comment: weird things happen when I resized and rotated the instancer ( "Duplication" changed to "instancing" in 2.8, instancer is able to be hide now ) before parenting objects to it. All object messed up in different locations.

Comment: @Albert I tried rotating and scaling the instancer, everything seemed to behave normally. Could you describe more clearly what went wrong?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I created multiple objects 'A1,A2,A3' and then edit each of it ( G/R/S, extrude, etc. ). Parent all of it to the active selected 'B', then parent 'B' to an instancer. Each duplications of 'A1,A2,A3' rotates in random axis. I'm not sure which step cause this problem, probably ctrl a is needed on 'A1,A2,A3' before parenting.

Comment: array on z axis also not working in here.

Comment: @Albert Still unable to reproduce the issue on my end. Did Ctrl-A fix the issue?

Answer (score 12):

1. Select all the objects you want to multiply.
2. Make linked duplicates with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and place them at the proper distance.
3. Repeat your last step with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> as often as you like.

Another way for more flexible needs:

1. Select your objects.
2. Give them a keyframe with <kbd>I</kbd> > *location*.
3. If you want a row of ten objects, go nine frames forward and move your selection to the end of your substitute array. Set another *keyframe*
4. Enable *Dupliframes* for each of your objects in the *Object Properties*, *Duplication* panel. Adjust *start* and *end* accordingly or you'll get a hundred copies.
5. Use the *Graph Editor* to set the interpolation to linear with <kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd> if you need even distribution of your objects.
6. Make the *Duplis* real with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

This process makes it possible to move, scale and rotate your objects freely.

Comment: Wow, I never new about Shift+R.. Here I was pressing F3 constantly.. great shortcut :)

Answer (score 10):

One way to do that is to execute <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> / **Add** > **Group Instance** > *[group name]* to instance the group as a single object. Though it's basically an Empty, so we can't put an Array modifier on it, we can still <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> on the instance to create linked-duplicates.

**Edit:** For a more automated tool, we do need some basic scripting. I've written [a short operator](https://gist.github.com/adhihargo/6325992) to do just that. Here's the key part:

```
for count in count_product:
    loc = center + Vector([count[0] * self.offset[0],
                           count[1] * self.offset[1],
                           count[2] * self.offset[2]])

    dup_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(group.name + '_array.000', None)
    dup_obj.location = loc
    dup_obj.dupli_type = 'GROUP'
    dup_obj.dupli_group = group
    context.scene.objects.link(dup_obj)
```

It just creates an array of group instances along three axis:

[image: group_array]

Comment: Thanks, though it's more or less the same as selecting the group and duplicating that way.. Maybe some basic python to quickly place 30 or so along an axis?

Comment: You could use dupliverts: Define your group, create an instance of that group, make that *instance* a child of some mesh (say, a mesh that consists of an edge with 30 subdivisions), then enable dupliverts on the parent mesh.

Comment: @gandalf3: Edited my answer. I wrote a sample operator, sort of like Array modifier, but for Group instances. Can't upload a screenshot at the moment...