# It is possible to add modifiers to a group?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, groups

I made a group of different objects with different set of modifiers for each one. I wanted to add a lattice modifiers to this group to be able shape its form... it is possible? I tried with no sucess... It seems something very useful, i'm impressed something like this isn't implemented in blender yet...

Comment: Possible dupe of [Array a group of objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/array-a-group-of-objects).

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Modifier nodes are planned for someday, which would allow for this kind of thing. For now you will either have to add the modifiers manually or with a quick python script. Or apply the existing modifiers and join the objects with `Alt C` *> Mesh*, `Ctrl J`. Then add the modifier to the resulting object.

Comment: If you are asking how to add the same modifier to all the selected objects without having to do each one manually then you can select them all and add a modifier to one of them and then use Make Links(Ctrl+l) then choose->Modifiers.  It's not entirely clear what you are asking so I could be way off here.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Your tip may help me... thank you!;)

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm not wanted to join the meshes for memory saves (I've made copies ALT+D of these objects to reduce memory usage and render time) it is a high poly stairs handrail with a lot of details. But I've discovered that I can apply the same lattice for each one of the objects and then I'll be able to shape them all together. Lets hope that the ability of apply modifiers to mesh groups arrive soon in Blender. It will make the solution for these situations, a lot easier. Thanks for your explanations! ;)

Comment: @MarcClintDion Note that that will copy *all* the modifiers of the active object and overwrite any modifiers on the selected objects.

Comment: That's a good point.  I have an older version of the cgCookie QuickTools Addon and it can add a Sub-Surf Modifier to all selected objects at once without affecting the Modifiers that are already present.  Unfortunately, this ability does not extend to the other QuickTools Add Modifier options.  Maybe it can be adapted without too much trouble.  Maybe the newer versions have overcome this.

Answer (score 3):

Modifiers can be easily added using python.

```
target_lattice = bpy.data.objects['Lattice']

for obj in bpy.data.groups['Group'].objects:
    new_mod = obj.modifiers.new(type='LATTICE', name='Lattice')
    new_mod.object = target_lattice
    new_mod.strength = 0.5
```

Instead of all objects in a group you can use the selected objects with `bpy.context.selected_objects`

By changing `type='LATTICE'` you can add any modifier you want. Each modifier has different property names which can be seen in tooltips when python tooltips are enabled.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try that! Thank you so much! ;)