# Group mirror and armature

Tags: armature, mirror, groups

I've grouped objects and I would like to mirror them along x axis.
How to do it ?

Then I would like to animate this group as a single object. Do I use armature or something else ?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/array-a-group-of-objects. I don't think you can add modifier to a group of objects like you would to one object apart from linking modifiers' stack from object to object. As to animation it probably should be a separate question.

Comment: I've now figure it out that there is not group mirror avaiable. How to apply mirror modifier for all objects? Will mirror double the memory consumption ?

Comment: Do you mean to *add* modifier to multiple objects ? See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319/add-the-same-modifier-to-multiple-objects-at-once. Mirror will increase memory usage afaik, if you concerned about that use dupliframes as stated in the first link.