# How to add modifier to group instances

Tags: groups

How can i add modifier for a group instances. I have a group of object (cube, sphere, cylinder) and made a group. With `shift+A` > Group instance and added the group. I want that group instance to be added array modifier & curve modifier. 
[image]

I cannot apply array modifier and if i want to make the duplication frame i get only the empty not the objects.
[image]

Actually i want my file to be light not to be heavy adding many objects.[image]

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/array-a-group-of-objects)

Comment: @binweg its not group its group instances