# How to make array of group ?

Tags: modifiers, groups

When you made a group of objects, how to make array of them?

I know for shift+A to make group instance but I want to control it like array modifier.

Comment: Perhaps of help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/array-a-group-of-objects

Comment: Well, I think it is duplicate.